# Nokogiri: Finding all tags in a direct path, not including arbitrary levels of nesting

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Say I have an html document like:

```
<div id='findMe'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a href="bad">bad</a>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    This is some text and this is a <a href="good">link</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to capture all links instead the div #findMe, inside paragraphs tags, but not inside table or any other tags.  So, I want the one labeled "good", but not the one labeled "bad".  I'm trying:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(html).css('#findMe p a')
```

but that's capturing both links.  I also tried a more explicit xpath:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(html).css('#findMe').xpath('//p/a')
```

But that's doing the same thing.  How can I tell Nokogiri to only search a specific path down the tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `>` in CSS to select immediate descendant.

```
Nokogiri::HTML(html).css('#findMe > p > a')
```

Or use `/` in xpath:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(html).xpath("//div[@id='findMe']/p/a")
```

Comment: Ok, would this work if I want all `<p>` tags inside that div? and all `<a>` tags inside all of those?  I guess the question wasn't too clear here.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to do it, but I'm still not too comfortable with xpaths so if this isn't the best way feel free to post the more canonical way to achieve this.

```
Nokogiri::HTML(html).css(#findMe').xpath('//div/p/a')
```

Comment: Your XPath is selecting **all** the `div`s in your file (and ignoring the context of the `css()` selector.) The `css()` selector matches *one* element with the `findMe` ID, which happens to be that `div`, but then the XPath expression ignores that result and fetches a node-set of `a` elements from *all* divs. Is that what you really want?